# Invalid "requirements_file": path docs/requirements.txt does not exist

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs, requirements.txt

While updating the docs on my project using ReadTheDocs, I have no suddenly started getting this error:

```
Problem parsing YAML configuration. Invalid "requirements_file": path docs/requirements.txt does not exist
```

What's strange is that there very certainly is a docs/requirements.txt file, and, furthermore, I haven't even touched it between the commits that had passing RTD builds and when it started failing.

What exactly is causing the error doesn't appear to be in the logs:

```
Read the Docs build information
Build id: 7495313
Project: squiggle
Version: latest
Commit: 68b4ea3a22d740fce1bfdd5bd5af75ccf0cd5367
Date: 2018-07-16T17:54:43.712130
State: finished
Success: False


[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2018-07-16T23:19:18.575436, end-time: 2018-07-16T23:19:21.592819, duration: 3, exit-code: 0
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Lab41/squiggle.git .
Cloning into '.'...

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2018-07-16T23:19:21.683231, end-time: 2018-07-16T23:19:21.709477, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git checkout --force origin/master
Note: checking out 'origin/master'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 68b4ea3... Ok I'm giving up

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2018-07-16T23:19:21.790443, end-time: 2018-07-16T23:19:21.801738, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git clean -d -f -f


[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2018-07-16T23:19:21.922702, end-time: 2018-07-16T23:19:21.931726, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git branch -r
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

Here is the [build history](http://readthedocs.org/projects/squiggle/builds/) of the project as well as its [repo](https://github.com/Lab41/squiggle).

Comment: I just started seeing this as well for https://readthedocs.org/projects/flask-jwt-extended/builds/. I am very curious what's going on here, but am glad to hear it's not just me.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a [bug in ReadTheDocs](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/4378) that has [been addressed](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/pull/4379).